# What is different between Passing by value and Passing by reference using C#

Tags: c#

I have difficulty understanding the difference between passing by value and passing by reference. Can someone provide a C# example illustrating the difference?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-a-parameter-passed-by-reference-vs-passed-by-value

Comment: That's *sort of* a duplicate, but this specifically asks for C# examples - whereas there are no C# examples at all in the referenced question. A lot of good *general* discussion, certainly, but I don't think it really hurts to have language-specific ones too.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Isn't the right solution to stick an answer with C# syntax into the existing question? Presumably editing an existing answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In general, read [my article about parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html).

The basic idea is:

*If the argument is passed by reference, then changes to the parameter value within the method will affect the argument as well.*

The subtle part is that if the parameter is a reference type, then doing:

```
someParameter.SomeProperty = "New Value";
```

*isn't* changing the value of the parameter. The parameter is just a reference, and the above doesn't change what the parameter refers to, just the data within the object. Here's an example of *genuinely* changing the parameter's value:

```
someParameter = new ParameterType();
```

Now for examples:

**Simple example: passing an int by ref or by value**

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int i = 10;
        PassByRef(ref i);
        // Now i is 20
        PassByValue(i);
        // i is *still* 20
    }

    static void PassByRef(ref int x)
    {
        x = 20;
    }

    static void PassByValue(int x)
    {
        x = 50;
    }
}
```

**More complicated example: using reference types**

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        PassByRef(ref builder);
        // builder now refers to the StringBuilder
        // constructed in PassByRef

        PassByValueChangeContents(builder);
        // builder still refers to the same StringBuilder
        // but then contents has changed

        PassByValueChangeParameter(builder);
        // builder still refers to the same StringBuilder,
        // not the new one created in PassByValueChangeParameter
    }

    static void PassByRef(ref StringBuilder x)
    {
        x = new StringBuilder("Created in PassByRef");
    }

    static void PassByValueChangeContents(StringBuilder x)
    {
        x.Append(" ... and changed in PassByValueChangeContents");
    }

    static void PassByValueChangeParameter(StringBuilder x)
    {
        // This new object won't be "seen" by the caller
        x = new StringBuilder("Created in PassByValueChangeParameter");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Passing by value means a copy of an argument is passed. Changes to that copy do not change the original.

Passing by reference means a reference to the original is passed and changes to the reference affect the original.

This is not specific to C#, it exists in many languages.

Answer (score 0):

The digest is:

Passing by reference is used when you expect the function/method to modify your variable.

Passing by value when you don't.